# Solve system solutions

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

The number of actual system solutions
$ \begin{cases}
a^2=b+2\\
b^2=c+2 \\
c^2=a+2\\
\end{cases}$
is equal to:

Solution:

$\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1\implies 2\cos 2\theta=(2\cos\theta)^2-2$.

Using this results in all $8$ solutions to the system.

$(2,2,2)$, $(-1,-1,-1)$, and cyclic permutations of $\left(2\cos\frac{2\pi}{7},2\cos\frac{4\pi}{7},2\cos\frac{6\pi}{7}\right)$ and $\left(2\cos\frac{2\pi}{9},2\cos\frac{4\pi}{9},2\cos\frac{8\pi}{9}\right)$

How can i solve this in a simpler way
(Without using trigonometry)

Comment: Trigo is a good way to solve it. If you tried to substitute the equations, you would still end up with a degree 8 polynomial that you have to recognize looks like the Chebyshev polynomial for $\cos 8 \theta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^2=b+2 \tag1$$
$$b^2=c+2 \tag2$$
$$c^2=a+2 \tag3$$

By successive eliminations
$$(1) \implies b=a^2-2$$
$$(2) \implies c=a^4-4a^2-2$$
$$(3) \implies a^8-8 a^6+20 a^4-16 a^2-a+2=0\tag 4$$

$(4)$ can be factorized as
$$(a-2) (a+1) \left(a^3-3 a+1\right) \left(a^3+a^2-2 a-1\right)=0$$ Each cubic equation has three real roots that you can express using ... the trigonometric method !